# How to omit the first row in an excel import into a DataTable

Tags: c#, azure, datatable, azure-sql-database

The issue I have is I have a spreadsheet to import (on azure so I can't use the excel connector) but there are two rows on the top of the sheet. The first one I need to remove because the second row has the column names. The rest of the rows are the data.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
FileStream stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
excelReader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();
dt = result.Tables[0];
if (dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString() == "Category Info") { dt.Rows[0].Delete(); dt.AcceptChanges(); }
```

The data imports into the data table but then I need to delete the first row because someone decided it was a good idea to have two rows for the header. :(

When I include the "if" statement, I get an error that columns are missing from my import.

The challenge I'm trying to solve is allowing the user to import an excel file in a specific format onto a web application running on AZURE and as far as I know, the Excel libraries are not available on Azure... hence, bulk copy.

I also tried:

```
DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();
if (result.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString() == "Category Info") { result.Tables[0].Rows[0].Delete(); result.AcceptChanges(); }
dt = result.Tables[0];
```

Still getting the result "Column 'DataPointX' does not belong to table Sheet."

Answer (score 1):

> "Column 'DataPointX' does not belong to table Sheet."

If you retrieve row’s cell by using `dt.Rows[RowIndex]["DataPointX"]` but the DataTable does not contain the column **DataPointX**, which will throw the above error message. Please debug the code to check the variable `dt` and view the contents of dt via the ***DataSet Visualizer*** to make sure the column **DataPointX** is existing.

[image]

Besides, I use the code that you provided to read data from the below Excel file on my side, and I find the DataPointX will missing if it is **number**.

```
//read data from excel, same as yours

excelReader.Close();
dt = result.Tables[0];

if (dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString() == "Category Info")
{
    dt.Rows[0].Delete();
    dt.AcceptChanges();
}

GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

*GridView output data*

[image]

If the column DataPointX are filled with number in your excel file, please try to change cell format to **text** and test if it could fix the issue.

*My test Excel file (data of DataPointX field is number, data of DataPointY field is text)*

[image]

Comment: Excellent response. I will investigate and report back. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, so when I browse the dt object after loading it with data, I see the columns are still labeled as if that first row was not removed.

Comment: The issue is: I have two rows on the top of the sheet, I need to remove the first row because the second is the one with the column names.

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out and this is acceptable:

```
FileStream stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = excelReader.AsDataSet().Tables[0];

Int16 shift = 0;
if (dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString() == "Some Text in the header")
{
    shift = 1; //If the first row is a header, we need to shift everything up one row.
}

foreach (DataColumn Col in dt.Columns)
{
    Col.ColumnName = dt.Rows[shift].ItemArray[Col.Ordinal].ToString();
}
```